# Enable Webiopi CORS request

Tags: python, angular, http, webiopi

I'd like to call the Webiopi REST API from my angular application in a browser running on the Raspberry. As Webiopi HTTP server doesn't allow CORS request, I have created a proxy with apache that sends the `Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"` header.

This is working fine, however the call to the REST API throws many errors mainly because the browser sends an OPTIONS request to the server in case of a CORS request to check wether it is allowed or not. But the webiopi http handler doesn't handle the OPTIONS verb at all.

So I started to write it into the code myself with zero python experience. In the file python/webiopi/protocols/http.py I have added at the end:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.send_response(200,"ok")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    self.end_headers()
```

Now it doesn't throw any error but doesn't give me the proper response to my GET request. It just stops after the OPTIONS. The request and response looks like this:

**Request headers:**

```
OPTIONS /GPIO/1/value HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://192.168.1.108:51443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Raspbian Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 22:06:28 GMT
Server: WebIOPi/0.7.1/Python3.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**General (from chrome network tab):**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/GPIO/1/value
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Where is my GET request? Why do I see only the OPTIONS which by the way I'm not initiating at all?

**The request from angular:**

```
this.http.get<number>(this.route+'GPIO/'+gpio+'/value').subscribe(result => {
                resolve(result);
            })
```

Comment: Do you get any sort of error message in the browser console?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I had to enable all headers in OPTIONS, posted the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable all headers to the http server:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.send_response(200,"ok")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    self.end_headers()
```